# Android: How to change background of Title Bar of DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I managed to apply a custom theme to the DatePickerDialog but there's still a Blue part in the header of the DatePickerDialog

how can I change it ?

Please find the screenshot and my code below . .

This is the theme:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="DiglrTheme" parent="android:Theme">        
            <item name="android:background">#3f863c</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

And this is where I applied it in the Activity :

```
 @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:            
            return  new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.DiglrTheme ,mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);                
        }
        return null;
    }
```

[image: Styling DatePickerDialog]

Comment: <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">#3f863c</item>

Comment: No, this doesn't work also you can't apply style like this by adding color directly , I created style and applid it with @style/Custom_style_name   but it didn't change the blue part . . I don't think that this part is the Window's title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
android:background = "@android:color/transparent"
```